# Avoid constructor with empty base class with virtual method

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, initialization, c++17

I have an empty base class with a virtual function. Is there any way I can avoid manually implementing the constructors of Derived in order to be able to initialize it?

```cpp
struct Base
{
    virtual int f(int) const = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = 0; 
};

Base::~Base() {}

struct Derived: public Base
{
    int v;

    int f(int) const override{ return v;};
};

int main() 
{
    return Derived{5}.f(3);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way I can avoid manually implementing the constructors of Derived in order to be able to initialize it?

No. Having a base class and virtual functions causes `Derived` not being an aggregate.

If you remove the `virtual` functions, you have aggregates and you can

```
return Derived{{}, 5}.f(3);
//             ^^ explicitly initialize base class
```

but as this is not the point of your question, this is no solution to it.

Comment: This made me sad. So much boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

Both the base class and the derived class has an implicit default constructor (as well as copy and move), and there is no need to manually implement those.

Neither class is an aggregate, so they cannot be initialised using list initialisation without implementing a custom constructor that accepts compatible list of arguments. This is why your example program does not work. Neither class can become an aggregate without removing the virtual member function.

So, your options are:

- Don't use list initialisation, except with an empty list of parameters which is a special case that performs value initialisation which invokes the default constructor
- or provide a custom constructor for the list of arguments that you want to pass
- or remove the virtual member function so that the classes become aggregates, and their members can then be initialised directly with list initialisation